# What type of waveform is described by this fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

A signal with a **time of 0.2 miliseconds** is described by the below equation:

> $$
> f(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sin(\omega_0x) - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2\omega_0x) 
>  +\frac{1}{3}\sin(3\omega_0x) - \frac{1}{4}\sin(4\omega_0x) + \frac{1}{5}\sin(5\omega_0x)
> $$

The question is to **determine the type of waveform described by the fourier series graphically**. I know that it is a sinusoidal wave form, but can't figure out how to graph this particular equation and show in clear steps how I came to that conclusion.

In essence, I am looking for help in actually figuring out how to graph this equation to show what type of waveform this fourier series describes.

Comment: In brief, you are asking how to graph a real valued function given a closed form expression for the function. Have you graphed other functions before? Have you tried the [Desmos graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)?

Comment: Thanks @Somos I have, but couldnt figure out how to graph it on desmos.

Comment: It is very simple. Just type `1/2\t+sin(x)-1/2\t sin(2x)+1/3\t sin(3x)-1/4\t sin(4x)+1/5\t sin(5x)` where `\t` is the tab character.

Comment: @somos that's what I did and I got a really strange graph.. plus is w not equal to 2pi*f, therefore you would need that in your equation.

Anyway, my main struggle is figuring out how to determine the type of waveform, which the graph hasn't helped with this far.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "type of waveform"? It is clearly periodic. What else are you looking for?